# Mounted volume does not appear in FTP client using vsftpd

Tags: mount, ftp, fedora, filezilla, vsftpd

Using vsftpd and filezilla, I can connect and view files and directories in a user's home directory. An empty directory is initially visible, but after I mount an ext2 volume to it, the directory disappears in my client.

I mount the volume with this command, which gives no output:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /home/user/dir
```

I also tried mounting like this:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /var/ftp/pub/dir
sudo mount --bind /var/ftp/pub/dir /home/user/dir
```

I can then view the files from the volume in my filesystem, but in both cases, the directory `dir` is listed in my ftp client before mounting, and disappears after mounting.

I tried with setting the ownership of the directory+files to both root:root and user:user and set the permissions to 755.

My `vsftpd.conf` file is configured as so:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=NO
local_umask=022
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
```

How come vsftpd won't serve the mounted directory?

Answer (score 1):

If you mount the folder with the `allow_other` option, the disk will show up:

```
s3fs bucket /mnt/bucket -o allow_other
```